# SignalR routing issue, get 200 ok but response empty

Tags: asp.net, routes, signalr

I have an existing MVC application which I am integrating a hub into, now I have setup the hub like so:

```
routeTable.MapHubs("myapp/chat/room", new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true, EnableDetailedErrors = true, EnableJavaScriptProxies = true });
```

Then in the clientside I am connecting like so:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection(SystemConfiguration.ServiceUrl + "/myapp/chat/room", { useDefaultPath: false });
var hub = this.Connection.createHubProxy("ChatHub"); // Same name as on the hub attribute
connection.start().done(function(){ /* do stuff */});
```

Then I see the HTTP Request like so:

`http://localhost:23456/myapp/chat/room/negotiate?_=1374187915970`

Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true, true
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    content-type, x-requested-with, *
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    http://localhost:34567, http://localhost:34567
Access-Control-Max-Age  10000
Cache-Control   no-cache
Content-Length  420
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date    Thu, 18 Jul 2013 22:52:18 GMT
Expires -1
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
```

Request Headers

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host    localhost:23456
Origin  http://localhost:34567
Referer http://localhost:34567/myapp/chat?chatId=1764a2e3-ff6f-4a17-9c5f-d99642301dbf
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
```

The response though contains no body, its got a 200 status though... I am debugging on the server and the hub methods are never hit. The only non standard thing in this scenario is that I have a custom CORS HttpModule which intercepts traffic and appends the CORS required headers, as you can see in the response, so not sure if this confuses SignalR's CORS support in some way. Anyway I can see the HttpModule being hit so it goes past there fine, but is somehow lost between there and the hub.

Tried googling but not much info on this topic...

Comment: Are there any javascript errors logged in the browsers console?

Comment: Nope. The request above is hilighted as red in the firefox console, but I presume thats because there is no content or something, but no actual JS errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be down to my CORS handling at HttpModule level, it must somehow conflict with SignalR... if I put a check in the module to see if the URL contains "chat/room" and just ignore the request if needed it then works fine, however it feels like a hack, but at least it works now.